# My text editor generating extra braces, how to get rid of it

Tags: javascript, django, quill

I need to setup a text editor for better posting capability into my project (Django 2.0) and I'm using quilljs for it. This is working but some error is attached along with the post.

Code here

```
 <form action="" method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}  
      <input name="description" type="hidden">
      <div id="editor-container">
      </div>

      <input class="ui button" type="submit" value="Post" />
    </form>
```

Javascript

```
var quill = new Quill("#editor-container", {
    modules: {
        toolbar: [
            ['bold', 'italic'],
            ['link', 'blockquote', 'code-block', 'image'],
            [{
                list: 'ordered'
            }, {
                list: 'bullet'
            }]
        ]
    },
    placeholder: 'Compose an epic...',
    theme: 'snow'
});
var form = document.querySelector('form');
form.onsubmit = function() {
    // Populate hidden form on submit
    var about = document.querySelector('input[name=description]');
    about.value = JSON.stringify(quill.getContents());

    console.log("Submitted", $(form).serialize(), $(form).serializeArray());

};
```

after post, the result is like that

> {"ops":[{"insert":"A robot who has developed sentience, and is the only robot of his kind shown to be still functioning on Earth.\n"}]}

How to get rid of this extra braces. 
TIA

Comment: SHould you be allowing js to be entered int the text editor?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the result you are getting

> {"ops":[{"insert":"A robot who has developed sentience, and is the only robot of his kind shown to be still functioning on Earth.\n"}]}

is not an error. Quill's getContents() function returns the text in the editor in **JSON** format (that's why those braces are there). Further you are stringifying that JSON to get the string.

Have a look at this playground page from Quill to understand the returning data format: [link](https://quilljs.com/playground/#form-submit)

---

If you just want to remove those braces and get the input text, you can either get it at client-side in onsubmit method itself or on server-side in django's view where you receive form data.

**1. Client-side in JS:**

```
form.onsubmit = function() {
    // Populate hidden form on submit
    var about = document.querySelector('input[name=description]');
    //get JSON from quill editor
    var jsonData = quill.getContents();
    //access "insert" data from the JSON
    about.value = jsonData.ops[0].insert;

    console.log("Submitted", $(form).serialize(), $(form).serializeArray());
};
```

**2. Server-side in Python:**

```
import json

...
#get JSON String from the request and parse it to python JSON dictionary
jsonData = json.loads(req.body.description)
#access "insert" data from the JSON
inputText = jsonData["ops"][0]["insert"]
...
```

**Note:** This is only for getting the plain text data **(if present)** from Quill. You can access the other formatted text also from the JSON.